# Fill matrix by data from pandas.DataFrame, skip NaN

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, nan

I want to fill the matrix `ref` using `pd.DataFrame` `xxx` but skip the `NaN`.

```
print xxx
OUT >> 
   intensity name  rowtype1  rowtype2
0        100    A         1       4.0
1        200    A         2       NaN
2        300    B         3       5.0
```

Then I fill the matrix by `ref[rowtype,col] = intensity` where I have 2 `rowtype`.

```
ref = np.zeros(shape=(7,4))
for idx, inte, name, r1, r2 in xxx.itertuples():
    ref[r1,idx] = inte
    ref[r2,idx] = inte # error because of NaN in rowtype2

print ref
```

How can I skip `NaN` here? 
I know one way to use `drop.na()` but it has to create new dataframe which has `rowtype2` and `intensity`. I would like to have quick simple way, like just jump across `NaN` with `intensity = 200` to next `rowtype2 = 5` with `intensity = 300`.

---

Additional info:

1) Here is how to create `xxx`

```
prot = ['A','A','B']
calc_m = [1,2,3]
calc_m2 = [4, np.nan,5]
inte = [100,200,300]
xxx = pd.DataFrame({'name' : pd.Series(prot),
                    'rowtype1': pd.Series(calc_m),
                    'rowtype2': pd.Series(calc_m2),
                    'intensity': pd.Series(inte)
                    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this option using [**`melt`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html), and then setting the index of `ref` using numpy's indexing vs. using a for loop

```
set = xxx.reset_index().melt(['intensity','index'],['rowtype1','rowtype2']).dropna()

ref[set.value.astype(int).values,set['index'].values] = set.intensity.values
```

which gives you

```
array([[   0.,    0.,    0.,    0.],
       [ 100.,    0.,    0.,    0.],
       [   0.,  200.,    0.,    0.],
       [   0.,    0.,  300.,    0.],
       [ 100.,    0.,    0.,    0.],
       [   0.,    0.,  300.,    0.],
       [   0.,    0.,    0.,    0.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand what behavior you are looking for, but the pandas dropna() command has the "subset" argument... for example, dropping all rows with NaN in the rowtype2 column could be done with

```
xxx.dropna(subset=['rowtype2'],inplace=True)
```

That way, you would drop only rows with NaN in the rowtype2 column.